# Implementing Table partitioning in SQL server having alwayson setup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on Table partitioning on selected tables. It is working fine in lower environments as the environments are pretty simple with single SQL server in each environment.
My production environment is using AlwaysOn setup for High availability with one primary and one secondary node. I stormed my brain to implement table partitioning in such environment and came across below possible implementations and corresponding problems:

1. Turn off AlwaysOn from Primary-> Implement partitioning on Primary-> (Ask: If I turn on AlwaysOn on primary, will the partitions get reflect in secondary?)
2. Without turning off AlwaysOn from Primary apply partitioning on Primary (Ask: Is it possible? If yes, will the partitions get reflect in secondary and what will be the possible impact on performance?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you take your database out of the Availability Group or not, the partitioning will be reflected at the secondary. This is due to the fact that the secondary is using transaction log records to apply any changes that happen at the primary.

One thing that will inform your decision is whether or not this operation will generate a lot of transaction log. If it will, all of that activity will need to be replayed at the secondary as well. It could be more efficient to take the database out of the AG, do your change, take a full or differential backup, and then use that to re-establish the AG.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ben. In my case, tables to be partitioned are huge in size. Definitely it is going to generate huge transaction logs.  So better I will follow what you have suggested.